# BlackBerry - Play mp4 video from remote server

Tags: java, video, blackberry, media

I am using a [BrowserSession](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/browser/BrowserSession.html) to play audio and video files.  The audio files play without problem, but when I try to play a video file, the browser displays garbage characters.

How do I play video files from a remote server, especially .mp4 files?

I'm using this code to play the media:

```
BrowserSession browserSession = Browser.getDefaultSession();
//url is the path to the media file from remote server  
browserSession.displayPage(url);  
browserSession.showBrowser();
```

Found the answer: https://github.com/mjrusso/videostreaming-blackberry

Comment: What is the "Content-Type" being sent back to the client for the video file?  What format is it encoded in?

Comment: The content type being sent back is "text/plain" but the format of these video is mp4, my iPhone version of the app can play these video without problem.

Comment: I've tested the app on both BlackBerry Storm and BlackBerry Torch. BB Storm displays garbage characters, BB Torch asks users to save the file as MP4, users can play the video after saving to the phone, BB Browser doesn't play the video directly. Any help would be appreciated !