# blackberry browser - video format

Tags: html, blackberry, video, mobile

It looks like the browser on a Blackberry doesn't support either HTML 5 or Flash...

What's the best format to display video in it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[BrowserSession](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11844/Browser_session_management_438294_11.jsp) is useful to paly video and audio formats in Blackberry.Visit following 
 links useful for you.

[BlackBerry - Play mp4 video from remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151386/blackberry-play-mp4-video-from-remote-server).
If you need information about Browser session the following link might help you.
http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11844/Browser_session_management_438294_11.jsp

Comment: I was actually looking for the html code that I can use on a website so blackberry understands the format...

Answer (score 1):

You would use the object tag e.g.

```
<object data=FILENAME type=MIMETYPE>
```

You can see the supported video formats on different phones [here (PDF)](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/smartphone_users/deliverables/18349/711-01774-123_Supported_Media_Types_on_BlackBerry_Smartphones.pdf).
[Source](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2009/08/blackberry-browser-embedded-media-content-automatic-playback-how-to/)

Answer (score -1):

Latest version of blackberry (from 6.0). but however it is not that intelligent to play videos efficiently.

Is your application using native code ? If yes, then go for manual player or invoke default browser which has capability to play videos. I have done the same way for you tube videos.