# How to direct play video on Blackberry application?

Tags: java, blackberry, browser, video-streaming

I want to play video file on blakcberry by programming 
My source :

```
url = "http://a1408.g.akamai.net/5/1408/1388/2005110405/1a1a1ad948be278cff2d96046ad90768d848b41947aa1986/sample_mpeg4.mp4";

    BrowserSession browserSession = Browser.getDefaultSession();

    browserSession.displayPage(url);
    browserSession.showBrowser();
```

When I run application, a popup is shown to confirm (Open, Save, Cancel) and then if I press Open button the video is played.

How can I invisible the popup. I mean , I want to direct play video , don't shown popup confirm.

Please hep me if you know that !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  Thanks you very much.

---

Dear HelpMeToHelpYou !
I have checked your sample code but it seem still appear dialog when i run apps.
This is capture screen when have dialog confirm 
[image]

Comment: Does this help? http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17968/Create_BB_app_that_plays_a_video_in_a_UI_field_739692_11.jsp

Comment: Thanks @eboix but my issue is difference with your link support...

Comment: My issue same here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151386/blackberry-play-mp4-video-from-remote-server/8651251#8651251

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi just try following code it works fine for OS5 and above

```
 url="http://a1408.g.akamai.net/5/1408/1388/2005110405/1a1a1ad948be278cff2d96046ad90768d848b41947aa1986/sample_mpeg4.mp4";
        BrowserFieldConfig browserFieldConfig = new BrowserFieldConfig();
        browserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE, BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);
        browserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED,Boolean.TRUE);
        browserFieldConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.ALLOW_CS_XHR,Boolean.TRUE);
        browserField=new BrowserField(browserFieldConfig);
        browserField.requestContent(url);
        add(browserField);
```

Bellow Os5

try the following code this is also work for os5

```
public class browserScreen extends MainScreen
{
    String url;

    public browserScreen() {


        url = "http://a1408.g.akamai.net/5/1408/1388/2005110405/1a1a1ad948be278cff2d96046ad90768d848b41947aa1986/sample_mpeg4.mp4";

        BrowserSession browserSession = Browser.getDefaultSession();

        browserSession.displayPage(url);
        browserSession.showBrowser();

        new keypress();



    }
}
class keypress extends Thread
{
    public keypress() {
        try {
            sleep(1000);
            start();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("===================================click on enter");
         KeyEvent press= new EventInjector.KeyEvent(EventInjector.KeyEvent.KEY_DOWN, (char) (Keypad.KEY_ENTER), KeypadListener.STATUS_NOT_FROM_KEYPAD);
            EventInjector.invokeEvent(press);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried but not work! Because BrowserFieldConfig class is combine error with OS4.5 !!! I'm developing on OS4.5... Don't have this class.

Comment: kk you should mansion os name before posting question. i will try this in 4.5

Comment: Same issue  ---  http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Browser-session-surpress-dialog/m-p/313536/highlight/false#M55521

Comment: hello please check above code let me know is it working or not

Comment: Dear HelpMetoHelpYou. Because I don't have permission for " Anser my question" so I edit the first my question... Please re-read my question@@...

Comment: hi i will definitely help you please come here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-and-java

Comment: Dear my friend. I tried to changed another URL for play video. URL1 : http://a1408.g.akamai.net/5/1408/1388/2005110405/1a1a1ad948be278cff2d96046ad90768d848b41947aa1986/sample_mpeg4.mp4  . It's about 200Kb... and URL2 = Myserver/11/1221/sam.mp4. It's about 2M... So , when I run apps with URL2. one popup is shown on screen with content " The item you selected can not displayed. Do u want to save or cancel?" ... What is error???